# Google PlusOne button has some bottom margin

Tags: javascript, css, google-plus-one

[image: plusone compared to others]

I'd like to know if the issue I see is just for my site or if this is a known issue.

I have some social widgets that align pretty well, but for some reason the PlusOne is not aligned correctly.

I used Firebug to compare it with the Facebook Like widget, and according to the CSS, they are both exactly the same height and neither have margins or padding. Their css looks identical.

```
<div>
        <fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="90" action="like" font="verdana" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>

        <g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/sharethis.js#publisher=d9550e2f-f25a-4e2e-ae45-7a51cf7e3d46&amp;type=website&amp;buttonText=Share%20item!&amp;embeds=true&amp;style=rotate"></script>
        &nbsp;<font face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='1'><a href='/mmh/recommend/send.php?prodid=$!product.id'><img src="/images/icons/icon_email.gif" border="0"> Email item</a></font>
</div>
```

Actually I have a link where the same thing i happening: http://news.makemeheal.com/celebrity-plastic-surgery/jennifer-aniston-weighs-on-prince-williams-hair-loss/ (if necessary, reduce your window size so Fbook and G+ are on the same line)

Comment: Unfortunately the page is protected

Comment: could you show me  the markup for just the faceook and google plus one

Comment: edited the question to show markup

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<span style="position:relative; top:3px">
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-annotation="none"></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using relative positioning, e.g. add the following CSS to the G+ button:

```
position: relative;
top: 5px; /* Or whatever looks right */
```

Although, while it may fix your problem it doesn't exactly show the cause of the issue.

Comment: I take it back - it works in "theory". In practice, they don't let you add style to the tag itself, as far as I know. Their javascript overwrites my inline styles

Comment: Can you put the G+ button in a container (e.g. a `div`) and apply the styling to that? There's no way Google can edit the style of a container element.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. I put the Google+ code in a `<div>` and used CSS to limit the `max-height` property of `<div>` to `70px` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Put a div (class=froogle) around the +1 button, float them all and then style as you want. It worked for me:

```
.facebook-like, .twitter-share-button, .froogle {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```